# Iterate plots for each column in R

Tags: r, plot

I want to make a qqplot for each column (except the last one) in this dataset:

`data("pottery", package = "HSAUR2")`

This is what I have so far, but it only plots out the last column:

```
par(mfrow=c(3,3))
for (i in ncol(pottery[, 1:9])){
    qqnorm(pottery[, i], main = names(pottery[i]))
    qqline(x)
}
```

I don't think this should be hard, but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Thanks as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
par(mfrow=c(3,3))
for (i in 1:ncol(pottery[,1: ncol(pottery) - 1 ])){  
qqnorm(pottery[, i], main = names(pottery[i]))
   qqline(pottery[, i])
}
```

I changed two things in your script. i in 1:ncol(pottery) means that you want to go across that range from the start to however many columns there are. When you said  i in ncol(pottery), that just says, i in last column. And then I wrote pottery[,ncol(pottery) - 1 ] which says you want to ignore the last column.

Comment: Doubtful. The number of columns in `pottery[,ncol(pottery) - 1 ]` will always be 1.

Comment: I see that you fixed the error. (Always better to post tested code.)

Comment: yep sorry, typed it quickly. Thanks for highlighting it.

Comment: I also think you should now fix the problems with the qqlines not matching up with the qqplots. I happened to have an 'x'-object in my workspace but would have seen an error it there were not one. The questioner may have something in his workspace but I doubt that is what was desired.

Comment: that hardly needs much fixing. x = pottery[, i]

Comment: Yes. Please do fix it.

Comment: Thanks! I clearly didn't understand the iteration. Appreciate the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Using `ggplot2` and `tidyr` to convert the data from wide to long:

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(pottery, condition, measurement, Al2O3:BaO, factor_key = TRUE) %>%
  ggplot(aes(sample = measurement)) +
  facet_wrap(~ condition, scales = "free") +
  stat_qq() +
  stat_qq_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution! But I would advise against using color here since it's redundant--and actually distracting.

Comment: @user2363777 You're totally right. Corrected. I did not remove that argument by mistake, it was needed in a plot where all Q-Q plots were not faceted. Thanks.